# Puedo hacer una peticion por websocket desde Angular?

Tags: angular, api, websocket

Estoy tratando de hacer esto como un pequeño proyecto personal. Quiero tratar de conectarme a la API de [poloniex](https://docs.poloniex.com/#ticker-data) , ellos ahí ofrecen un apartado para conectar por websocket a su api y obtener datos de algunas criptos.

Instale el paquete ngx-socket-io e hice esto:

este es mi app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'wss://api2.poloniex.com', options: {} };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

y cree este servicio donde hago la petición:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { map } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WsocketService {

  constructor(private socket: Socket) {}

  sendMessage() {
    this.socket.emit('channel', 1002 );
  }
  getMessage() {
    return this.socket.fromEvent('message').pipe(map((data:any) => data.msg));
  }

}
```

pero cuándo ejecto el código lo que obtengo es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

según la documentación de ngx-socket-io , en el metodo send debo enviar dos parametros (un string y el mensaje como tal ) pero en la api de Poloniex dice que debo enviar esto:

```js
{"command": "subscribe", "channel": 1002}
```

¿Como podría hacerlo? es posible hacerlo desde Angular directamente o debo construir un Backend para esto?

Espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar una solución o el camino correcto a seguir, gracias de antemano.